# Marshmallow get Imei natively with service call

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to get the Imei from a Galaxy S6 with native code!
I don´t can use Java-Code for it.

In Lollipop i Use

```
char *res = exec_get_out((char *) "service call iphonesubinfo 3");
```

to get IMEI and other characters, where i extract the Imeinumber.

Now with Marshmallow the new Permissions was released. I implemented It.
And i can get the imei like below with javacode.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 123);
    }

    String test = ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
```

But when I want to get the Number with the old native method i get the following result.

```
>null from uid 10169 not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE
```

I tried the "service call iphonesubinfo 3" command in adb shell and it gaves me the old result. But not in native Code.

Has anyone an Idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Has no one an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Android 5.x + or some phone device, Get IMEI or IMSI need require dynamic permission, when app startup.
2. service call iphonesubinfo x   The x is number for platform version, 7 is IMSI for Android 5.x ~ Android 7.x
3. In java code, you can use Runtim.getRuntime().exec(String cmd) to exectue this cmd line, and read Process inputStream for get it.
4. In C/C++ code, if device require permission, you can require permission by Java in Activity, and then call Native method with so.
5. About permission require:

1) Check permission:   int st = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(....);
   if st is PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  you can get IMEI/IMSI directly, if not,

2) Call ActivityCompat.requestPermission(Activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode)  and overried a method: onRequestPermission() in AppCompatActivity.

3) In onRequestPermission, check result for READ_PHONE_STATE permission is GRANTED, and call get IMEI/IMSI again.

Comment: The permission require flow is async, so you can't call cmd line when you call requestPermission, you should invoke cmd line in requestPermission callback and check result.